# Best XQuery IDEs for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ide, xquery

I am newbie to XQuery and I was hoping to find a tool which can help me edit xml documents and run xq queries in Ubuntu which can help accelerate my development/learning process.

Comment: I would also recommend IntelliJ in combination with the excellent XQuery plugin from Grzegorz Ligas at http://ligasgr.github.io/intellij-xquery/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [BASEX](http://basex.org/), it is a known tool for this kind of development, and you'll find in the repositories.

```
sudo apt-get install basex
```

Comment: If you want to use BaseX, better fetch it from the site; especially the IDE got improved enormously within the last time.

Answer (score 5):

If you do not want or need a Native XML Database, then oXygen XML Editor is probably the most popular tool among the serious XML geeks. You can edit, run and debug XQuery directly in oXygen.

Whilst it is a commercial product, it is very reasonably priced and there is a 30 day free trial, so you could see if it does what you want. http://www.oxygenxml.com.

Answer (score 3):

Check out eXist-db's eXide, a web-based XQuery IDE for eXist-db server.  See http://exist-db.org and, in particular for learning about eXide, this article about getting started: http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/development-starter.xml.